# Ramsey no ponzi condition

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, mathematical-economics, economic-growth, ramsey

[image]

[image]

Please help me understand how to create these functions, sometime they use "t" denote, sometime use "r" denote that make me feel confuse. Function (17) and from (19) to (23)